# Having trouble with Javascript. Haven't done this in a while

Tags: javascript, passwords

I'm trying to remember how to do this. I need to make two password fields and the passwords have to match. You check if they match by pressing a button. They have to have one uppercase and a number and be 4 characters long. If the passwords pass all that, you go onto another page.

so far I have

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function password()
{
var pwd1 = document.getElementsByName("pwd1").value;
var pwd2 = document.getElementsByName("pwd2").value;

if(pwd1 == pwd2)
{
window.location.href = '...';
}
else
{
Alert("Passwords do not match or your password is not longer than 4 characters");
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="password" name="pwd1"/>
<input type="password" name="pwd2"/>
<input type="button" onClick="password();" value="Submit" />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the error condition...

```
(pwd1 != pwd2 || pwd1.length >= 4 || ! pwd1.match(/\d/) || ! pwd1.match(/[A-Z]/))
```

Also, `alert()` does not have a capital and your selecting of the elements needs to subscript (`[0]`) the first.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TcQ2W/).

Comment: so this should be in place of the "pwd1 == pwd2" in the if statement?

Comment: @JoshI: Look at the fiddle and it should be clear. Don't feel dumb, even the greatest programmers had to start somewhere too.

Comment: Didn't see the fiddle link. And thanks for the encouragement :D

Comment: @Josh *doesn't work* doesn't really help anyone. It worked for me in the fiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry. If I type "Rawrrawr1" into both password fields. It still pops up with and error.

Comment: I would guess the real requirement was "at least 4 characters".

Answer (score 2):

Alright so your password function should look something like this:

```
function password() {
  var pwd1 = document.getElementsByName("pwd1")[0].value
    , pwd2 = document.getElementsByName("pwd2")[0].value
    , rules = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])/;

  if(pwd1 === pwd2 && pwd1.length >= 4) {
    if(rules.test(pwd1)) {
      //  redirect them now
      //  window.location.href = ...
    } else {
      alert('Password must contain at least 1 Capital letter and 1 digit');
    }
  }
  else{
    alert('Passwords must match and be at least 4 characters');
  }
}
```

Comment: First we check to make sure the passwords match and they are at least 4 characters in length. Then we check to make sure the password has at least 1 Uppercase character and 1 digit.

Comment: That regex doesn't test for 1 uppercase letter _and_ a digit, it tests for 1 uppercase _or_ a digit. The regex gurus can chime in with a better way, but the first way I thought of to test for both is something like the following: `/[A-Z].*\d|\d.*[A-Z]/` (where `\d` matches any digit).

Comment: Thanks for catching that. `/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])/` <---this also works

Comment: Cool, +1. I knew there would be a lookahead way to do it, but although I've been regexing for years and am quite comfortable with most other regex syntax I somehow managed to not know about lookaheads until recently and I'm still getting the hang of them.